# Access the Image Path in Html

Tags: html, file, src

The HTML File and Images folder was saved inside X Folder. The folder was Saved on my Desktop .However When tried to access the Image inside an image folder i cannot using the Html file.Image does not showed up on my  browser.

I really need to view the image on browser

Here is the Code

```
<td>
<img src="C:\Users\yy\Desktop\Staff\X\images\Special.png" width="86" height="117" alt=""></td>
<td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to give the full path. If you are using Local server(Xampp, Wamp etc..) than you can directly view the image on browser by opening url: localhost/path_of_your_image.

**For XAMPP:-** Give the path after the htdocs folder

**For WAMP:-** Give the path after www folder.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to start from where the page exists i.e. inside the /X/ folder

```
<img src="images/Special.png" width="86" height="117" alt=""></td>
```

Comment: OP said that image in desktop folder and html page in other path

Answer (score -1):

Image path **must be** within your **solution** Or under **Root folder** to access image from that folder